# Garbage Collection dispose of Datatable array in c#

Tags: .net, arrays, garbage-collection, datatable, dispose

i'm new in GC,
if i want to release a datatable array, does calling dispose() on all its datatables is enough? do i need to set null to the databale array too ? or to every datatable?

is this enough?:

```
 DataTable[] myTables = null;
             try
             {
                 myTables = DB.GetTables();

                 // use myTables....
             }
             finally
             {
                 // Dispose Data Tables
                 if (myTables != null)
                 {
                     foreach (DataTable dt in myTables)
                     {
                         if (dt != null)
                             dt.Dispose();
                     }
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Garbage Collector is Called itself on disposing of Application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Garbage Collection you have to do *nothing*.

Since DataTable implements IDisposable it is a good idea to call `Dispose()` on all of them (like you are doing). Setting references to `null` is only necessary in very rare situations. Not here.

But `Dispose()` is about releasing managed and unmanaged resources, not about Garbage collection.
For DataTbales Dispose() isn't actually necessary, but you don't want to bother knowing that. If a class has a Dispose() member, call it.

Comment: This reads to me like "if you do anything, like dispose stuff or null it out, GC will break".  As in, like it's a requirement that you not touch anything.  Just FYI.

Comment: @Chao, I was adding some more text.

Comment: Disposing objects that implement IDisposable is a good general practice, even with a garbage collector.

Comment: Ahh.  A bit better with it explained.  The first sentence still has that same problem, though.  "You don't have to do anything" is *not* the same thing as "you have to do nothing".

Comment: @Chao: and for GC that is true.

Comment: Cody, the simplest way to use implementers of IDisposable is with the using (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statement. Saves you forgetting to call it :)

Comment: @Topdown: I agree. When I typed that comment, Henk's edit hadn't been posted yet differentiating between GC and Dispose.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys :). i have just one more question: after i call dispose() on the above datatables , i can still see the data in them. aren't they suppose to be null after i call dispose? or will the GC release them later ....

Comment: @rodniko: The GC will recycle them later.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to do anything more.

The garbage collector knows when the array isn't used any more, and from that point in the code it can collect the array and everything that's inside it. Setting the array reference or any data table references to null is only unneccesary work.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is a very costly process, which is why in their wisdom Microsoft decided to automate it such that it runs when the system has spare capacity to run it, or when resources are becoming too low.

As a general rule of thumb therefore, you should only need to worry about explicit garbage collection when you are working with unmanaged objects (such as COM references) or where you are experiencing performance issues and you find that manual garbage collection can assist.

Comment: In the .net world, the only "manual garbage collection" is calling GC.Collect() directly, and there's hardly ever reason to do that.  You may be referring to disposables instead, in which case you may want to mention that.

Comment: thanks cHao. Totally agree with you. Maybe I am wrong, but when I first replied to the question I didn't see the word disposable there, and my terse reply focused solely on GC.